# Need help to write a lookup function for double hash implementation

Tags: c++, c, hash

I have implemented a double hash to store and find integers. Total number of items to be stored is ~5k. To do this, first I malloc a database of size ~10K. To create an entry, first I call the find function. If address returned has value '0' i.e. an empty slot, then item is inserted. Insertion works. However, for deletion and modify the lookup function fails sometime. This happens when the below sequence of events occurs.

entry1 is inserted in index 10.
entry2 is inserted in index 20.
entry3 got first collision at index 10, then seconds collision at index 20 and finally entry3 got inserted at index 30.
then entry2 gets deleted.
now a lookup for entry3 returns index 20 but this place has no value. Hence modify/delete fails.

Could you please suggest how to write a correct lookup function? I am not able to find out a condition to terminate the do-while loop without using "(*entry)->key != 0" check.

Thank you.

```
#define DB_HASH_LEN 10009

typedef struct node_ {
    u_int32_t key;
} hashnode_t;

int
vnid_db_open()
{
    u_int32_t db_size = DB_HASH_LEN * sizeof(*db_start);
    db_start = malloc(db_size);
    if (db_start == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        memset(db_start, 0, db_size);
        return 1;
    }
}

static inline u_int32_t
get_hash_index(u_int32_t key, u_int32_t hash_len)
{
    return (key % hash_len);
}

static inline u_int32_t
get_hash_offset(u_int32_t key, u_int32_t hash_len)
{
    return (1 + ((key/hash_len) % (hash_len - 1)));
}

void
find_entry(u_int32_t key, hashnode_t **entry)
{
    u_int32_t index = get_hash_index(key, DB_HASH_LEN);
    u_int32_t offset = get_hash_offset(key, DB_HASH_LEN);

    do {
        *entry = db_start + index;
        index = (index + offset) % DB_HASH_LEN;
    } while ((*entry)->key != 0 && (*entry)->key != key);
}

int
main(void)
{
    hashnode_t *node = NULL;
    u_int32_t op, key;
    vnid_db_open();

    while (1) {
        printf("op:");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        getchar();

        printf("key:");
        scanf("%d", &key);
        getchar();

        switch (op) {
            case(0):
                find_entry(key, &node);
                if (node->key == 0) {
                    node->key = key;
                    printf("inserted %d\n", key);
                } else if (node->key == key) {
                    printf("key %d exists for insert\n", key);
                } else {
                    printf("key %d not found for insert\n", key);
                }
                break;

            case(1):
                find_entry(key, &node);
                if (node->key == key) {
                    node->key = 0;
                    printf("deleted %d\n", key);
                } else {
                    printf("key not found %d for delete\n", key);
                }
                break;

            case(2):
                find_entry(key, &node);
                if (node->key == key) {
                    printf("found %d\n", key);
                } else {
                    printf("key not found %d for lookup\n", key);
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    return 0;
}

bash-3.2$ ./a.out
op:0
key:11111111
index 1121 offset 1111
inserted 11111111
op:0
key:11111112
index 1122 offset 1111
inserted 11111112
op:0
key:11111113
index 1123 offset 1111
inserted 11111113
op:0
key:2111113
index 9223 offset 211
inserted 2111113
op:0
key:2111114
index 9224 offset 211
inserted 2111114
op:0
key:2111114
index 9224 offset 211
key 2111114 exists for insert
op:0
key:2111115
index 9225 offset 211
inserted 2111115
op:0
key:9223
index 9223 offset 1 index 9224 offset 1 index 9225 offset 1 index 9226 offset 1
inserted 9223
op:1
key:2111113
index 9223 offset 211
deleted 2111113
op:2
key:9223
index 9223 offset 1
key not found 9223 for lookup
```

PS: Can I introduce a different lookup function based on the fact that if entry is not there in the hash table and then lookup will eventually do a full circle and index will match start_index and at this point I can terminate the search? Please see code below.

```
void
find_entry1(u_int32_t key, hashnode_t **entry)
{
    u_int32_t index = get_hash_index(key, DB_HASH_LEN);
    u_int32_t offset = get_hash_offset(key, DB_HASH_LEN);
    u_int32_t start_index = index;

    do {
        printf("index %d offset %d ", index, offset);
        *entry = db_start + index;
        index = (index + offset) % DB_HASH_LEN;
    } while ((start_index != index) && ((*entry)->key != key));

    printf("\n");
}
```

credit:

> [how to search using double hash in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136328/how-to-search-using-double-hash-in-c)

Comment: Please post the insert and delete functions too.

Comment: Your hash method is called "linear probing". See http://www.cs.rmit.edu.au/online/blackboard/chapter/05/documents/contribute/chapter/05/linear-probing.html for a good description from which you can fix your code.

Comment: Thank you. I have pasted the test data set. only for value < 10K, offset is 1. for bigger values offset is > 1. So for bigger values, this hashing is not linear   probing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the article I refer to in my comment, you must reserve a special value for "deleted key" so your search will not terminate when it finds zero.

So zero means "unused" and "special value" (for example -1) means, "deleted, so keep on looking". An entry with "special value" may be reused.

You must terminate your search when you are back at the "preferred index" where you started the search. It means "not found" when searching and "table is full" upon insert.

Lookup the article for the details.